A question concerning regularly varying functions
In my work I need some results about regulary varying functions, which I only have a very vague understanding.
A strongly related reference I found is "On the Existence of a Regularly Varying Majorant of an Integrable Monotone Function". In this interesting paper, Denisov showed the following.

Theorem. Suppose that ${f: \mathbb{R}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}}$is a nonincreasing function and ${\int_{0}^{\infty} f(t) d t<\infty}$. Then there exists a nonincreasing continuous function ${h: \mathbb{R}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}}$such that
(1) ${f(t) \leq h(t)}$ for all ${t \geq 0}$;
(2) ${\int_{0}^{\infty} h(t) d t<\infty}$;
(3) ${h}$ is a function of regular variation with exponent -1 .

What I need is somehow ``dual" to this result.

Question. Suppose that ${f: \mathbb{R}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}}$is a nonincreasing function and ${\int_{0}^{\infty} f(t) d t=\infty}$. Then there exists a nonincreasing continuous function ${h: \mathbb{R}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}}$such that
(1) ${f(t) \ge h(t)}$ for all ${t \geq 0}$;
(2) ${\int_{0}^{\infty} h(t) d t=\infty}$;
(3) ${h}$ is a function of regular variation with exponent -1.

Is this dual version true? Thank you in advance.

I believe that "regular variation with exponent $-1$" means $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(ax)}{f(x)}=a^{-1}$ for every $a>0$ (if you use some non-equivalent definition, let me know). If so, you are out of luck: $f$ can crawl at the level $1/T_j$ for the time $T_j$ for some very fast increasing sequence $T_j$ but every function $h$ satisfying $h(4x)\le h(x)/2$ will accumulate only the integral comparable to $\sqrt{T_{j-1}}/\sqrt{T_j}$ over that interval.

Thank you very much for your answer. I was too optimistic when thinking of it, and your example helps me understand regular variation better. Would you like to post it as answer so that I can accept it?
